# Conditional Formatting in SQL Reporting Services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SQL Reporting Services 2008, can you format a field conditionally? In Crystal Reports it is doable. I have a field which I want to be bold if another field is Y, and unbold if its value is N.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the FontWeight property of the field, and set it to an expression like this:

```
=iif(Fields!YourTestField.Value="Y","Bold","Default")
```

You can find FontWeight in the properties pane for the report item, or under Font -> Style -> Bold in the properties dialog (right click -> properties). Use the f(x) button to edit the formula.

Comment: For anyone else coming across this note that you can also conditionally format text mid-string within SSRS 2008.  You CANNOT do this in SSRS 2005, in 2005 you can only format the whole text box.

Comment: I didn't know about this (or the placeholder feature) till I read your comment and tried it out. Perhaps you could provide an another answer, eg, highlight text -> properties pane -> etc.

Comment: @Joel Mansford - I would love to know how to format conditionally mid-string.  Care to post an example?

Comment: @Vaccano, to conditionally format mid-string, you create a "placeholder" within the textbox (right click -> create placeholder, etc). The placeholder can then be formatted however you want.

Comment: @Peter - very true, but that is not conditional formatting (At least not how I think of it) it is static (because you have to put your text in the placeholder to format it).  I was able to get conditional formatting in my text by making it HTML and then running it through a global function that formatted it based on parameters.

Comment: @Vaccano: even better! That said, the placeholder can be data bound, so they do work for madlibs-style textboxes: "Dear [Title] [LastName], please find your TPS report on [Subject] below."